# 2gp error when installing unlock package into empty sandbox: Complains re existent Email Template in unfiled-public folder

Tags: salesforcedx, email-template, 2gp, install

We've created first version of our unlocked 2gp package.
Bunch of custom email templates have been packaged as a part of **unfiled$public** folder (including `MyCustomPackagedEmailTemplate` one).

Now when we are trying to install this package in an empty sandbox, it throws the following error:
`MyCustomPackagedEmailTemplate file is located in both the package you tried to install, and in either the unfiled-public folder or a user folder in this org. To install this package, either delete MyCustomPackagedEmailTemplate from this org, or move it to a different folder.`

But there is no single email template in this sandbox at all - the error message doesn't make a lot of sense.
Has anyone faced with something like? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

[image: Folder Creation]

The metadata for the folder should be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>folderName</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadWrite</publicFolderAccess>
</EmailFolder>
```